# Rails 4 Error Messaging with Stripe

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a form that submits bank account data to Stripe to create a token. I submit four attributes to Stripe - name, country, bank account number and routing number. The name is submitted as a param while the bank details are passed directly via coffeescript.

So when there is an error in the bank details, I get stripe error messaging in the form of an alert. When there is an error in the name, I get the standard Rails page with error details (on localhost). So on heroku, the error page is the standard "something went wrong" message.

How do I get the error in the name field (e.g. user only enters first name), to show up as an alert message instead of a rails error page? I want the user to know what the error is so they can re-enter the info.

here is my form code:

```
<h3>Edit Bank Account Details</h3>

  <% if @user.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation" class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissable">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
      <h4><%= pluralize(@luser.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this update from being saved:</h4>

      <ul>
      <% @user.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div id="stripe_error" class="alert alert-danger" style="display:none">
      <noscript>JavaScript is not enabled and is required for this form. Please enable it in your web browser settings.</noscript>
  </div>

<%= form_for @user, url: user_path, html: { method: :put } do |f| %>
     <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.label :full_name %><i> (as it appears in your bank account)</i>
      <%= f.text_field :bankaccname, class:"form-control" %>
     </div>

 <div class="form-group">
      <%= label_tag :country %>
      <%= text_field_tag :country, nil, { :name => nil, :'data-stripe' => "country", class: "form-control" } %>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= label_tag :routing_number %>
      <%= text_field_tag :routing_number, nil, { :name => nil, :'data-stripe' => "routingNumber", class: "form-control" } %>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= label_tag :account_number %>
      <%= text_field_tag :account_number, nil, { :name => nil, :'data-stripe' => "accountNumber", class: "form-control" } %>
    </div>

     <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.submit "Submit", class:"btn btn-primary" %>
     </div>

<% end %>
```